# Renaming files inside folders

Tags: linux, command-line, awk

I have several folders ,where each folder contain two files fastq.gz.
Usually they are named as sample_R1.fastq.gz and sample_R2.fastq.gz.
where sample_ can represent the folder name ,or something else.

But in my case the folders are :

1008_a
2085_a
2130_a
2192_a
2221_a
2242_a
2269_a
2482_a

And each of these folder consists of these files as :

1008_a 
Files :
**C85CBANXX_s6_1_O07_0452_SL137634.fastq.gz  C85CBANXX_s6_2_O07_0452_SL137634.fastq.gz**

2085_a :

**C7V65ANXX_s6_1_M19_0413_SL131164.fastq.gz  C7V65ANXX_s6_2_M19_0413_SL131164.fastq.gz**

How can I rename these files to just like **1008_a_R1.fastq.gz &
1008_a_R2.fastq.gz**  for folder 1008_a

**2085_a_R1.fastq.gz ,2085_a_R2.fastq.gz**  for folder 2085_a

And so on ,since all other folders have different kinds of patterns inside them.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: are all files in each folder have identical intermediate part `_s6_1_` and `_s6_2_` in its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

Sample folder structure (for ex. `1080_a` and `2085_a`):

```
$ tree 1008_a/ 2085_a/
1008_a/
├── C85CBANXX_s6_1_O07_0452_SL137634.fastq.gz
└── C85CBANXX_s6_2_O07_0452_SL137634.fastq.gz
2085_a/
├── C7V65ANXX_s6_1_M19_0413_SL131164.fastq.gz
└── C7V65ANXX_s6_2_M19_0413_SL131164.fastq.gz
```

---

The job:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep \
-regex ".*/[0-9]{4}_a/[[:alnum:]_]+_[12]_[[:alnum:]_]+\.fastq\.gz$" -exec bash -c \
'path=${0%/*}/; bn=${0##*/}; dir_n=${0%/*}; dir_n=${dir_n##*/}; 
 new_fn=$(sed -E "s/.+_([12])_.+(\.fastq\.gz)$/${dir_n}_R\1\2/" <<<"$bn"); 
 mv "$0" "$path$new_fn"' {} \;
```

---

Results:

```
$ tree 1008_a/ 2085_a/
1008_a/
├── 1008_a_R1.fastq.gz
└── 1008_a_R2.fastq.gz
2085_a/
├── 2085_a_R1.fastq.gz
└── 2085_a_R2.fastq.gz
```